# JavaScript convert to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I want to convert following Javascript function to C#. Can anyone help?

```
var vc = new ActiveXObject("NetLimiter.VirtualClient");
vc.Connect("localhost"/*addr*/, ""/*port or pipe*/);
var newRuleId = vc.SetRule(
    "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe",
    "limit",// rule type
    "in", // for download (incoming)
    "Internet",// zone
    true, // rule is enabled
    "1024", // 1024 Bytes
    "");
```

Comment: `c` tag removed; `javascript` tag added

Comment: Is this in web environment? and this code is currently run on client side? If it is, then converting to C# will make it run on server side and it is not what you wanted. So it is not a simple convert I'm guessing

Answer (score 3):

Use [AutomationFactory.CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee947172%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
dynamic vc = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("NetLimiter.VirtualClient");
```

Then everything else should be just fine.

Comment: Also, he should probably use `dynamic` instead of `var`.

Answer (score 2):

An ActiveXObject is a COM object. You can add a refence to that COM object in your C# project, then just instantiate it in your code and call any function you need.

Answer (score 1):

You would need the source for the ActiveXObject, but assuming that all the method calls were valid for that object - this would already compile in C#